# Found non-callable @@iterator in reactjs store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, store

> TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

```
const  middelware ={thunk};
 const Store = createStore(
      rootReducer,initialState, compose(
          applyMiddleware(...middelware),
           window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f=> f

const  middelware ={thunk};
 const Store = createStore(
      rootReducer,initialState, compose(
          applyMiddleware(...middelware),
           window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f=> f
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with React or Redux.

Answer (score 16):

Presumably `middleware` is an object and not an array, so here or somewhere else, you are doing the equivalent of this:

```
applyMiddleware(...{})
```

rather than:

```
applyMiddleware(...[])
```

Spreading arguments in function calls can only be done with arrays or other similar iterable objects.

Comment: What is the easiest/most elegant way of making something like applyMiddleware(...{}) work?

Comment: @Ryanless If you want to pass arguments to a function using values from an object, you need to explicitly pass them one at a time, or spread an array of the values you created ahead of time. Or just pass the object without the spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing Kevin Beal answer,

You can use:

```
applyMiddleware(...Object.values(middleware))
```