# react-redux <Provider> - Blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

My program was working just fine until I started working with 'react-redux'. Now I get a blank page on localhost and the console shows the error:

[Uncaught TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRA0c.png)

Here is my code:

store

```js
    import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
    
    import {sessionService} from 'redux-react-session';
    
    const initialState = {};
    const middlewares = {thunk};
    
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose (applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
    
    sessionService.initSessionService(store);
    
    export default store
```

rootReducer

```js
    import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
    
    //session
    import {sessionReducer } from "redux-react-session";
    
    const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
        session: sessionReducer
    });
    
    export default rootReducer;
```

App

```js
    import React from 'react';
    
    // Pages
    import Home from './pages/Home';
    import Login from './pages/Login';
    import Signup from './pages/Signup';
    import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
    
    
    //Styled Components
    import {StyledContainer} from './components/Styles';
    
    import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <StyledContainer>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup/>} />
    
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
    
              <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
    
              <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
    
            </Routes>
          </StyledContainer>
        </Router>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

index

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    
    
    // auth
    import {Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import store from "./auth/store";
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>            
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

I don't know what is wrong, and I don't have experience. I was trying to following a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCnHYz6TXA4
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited your question so the code examples are easier to read, and to include the error message from the image you uploaded.

Comment: `const middlewares = {thunk};` should be `const middlewares = [thunk];`.  `applyMiddleware()` takes each piece of middleware you want to apply as a single argument so you need to spread an array of middleware not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [Found non-callable @@iterator in reactjs store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552500/found-non-callable-iterator-in-reactjs-store)

You're trying to apply the spread operator to an object in your store setup. Plain javascript objects are not iterable, which is why you're getting an error about a non-callable @@iterator.

```js
const middlewares = {thunk};
    
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose (applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
```

`middlewares` should be an array:

```js
const middlewares = [thunk];
    
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose (applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
```